# How to inject bean reference into a Handler of xsocket?

Tags: spring, xsocket

I use xsocket to implement a socket server, and the handler of xsocket need inject an bean to do something. But, the reference aliway be NULL, I had logged the setter method, the setter method had been excused and the bean is not null in the log.

```
public class SocketServerHandler implements IDataHandler, IConnectHandler, IIdleTimeoutHandler, IConnectionTimeoutHandler, IDisconnectHandler, ApplicationContextAware {

private APIInvokeServer     apiInvokeServer;

@Override
public boolean onData(INonBlockingConnection connection) throws IOException, BufferUnderflowException,ClosedChannelException, MaxReadSizeExceededException {
    // read from connection
    String message = parseMessage(connection);

    final APIInvokeRequest invokeRequest;
    invokeRequest = apiInvokeServer.createInvokeRequest(trace);

    balabala...
}
public void setApiInvokeServer(APIInvokeServer apiInvokeServer) {
    OceanLog.system.error("--------setApiInvokeServer--------" + apiInvokeServer);
    this.apiInvokeServer = apiInvokeServer;
}
}
```

Is it because the Handler is a callback class? and do not init from spring?
what should I do then?

Comment: Is SocketServerHandler in Spring context?

Comment: yes,  <bean class="com.ocean.listener.socket.SocketAPIListener" init-method="startup" destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
  <property name="enable" value="${socket.enable}" />
 </bean>
  
 <bean id="socketServerHandler" class="com.alibaba.ocean.listener.socket.SocketServerHandler" scope="prototype">
  <property name="apiInvokeServer" ref="apiInvokeServer"/>
 </bean>

Comment: why do not try `@Autowired` annotation or `<property>` for injection?

Comment: I had tried both @Autowired and <property> , both of them return NULL when code running

Comment: can you post what have you tried and what you get?